# MySql Left outer Join not working as expected

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join

I've the following table structure.

Relationship between loan and loan_repayment is one-to-many

loan

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id   |                 loan_amount         |           loan_duration         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |                    60000            |                 3               
    2   |                    80000            |                 4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

loan_repayment

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id   |      loan_id     |      amount      |       month      |       status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |          1       |       20000      |         1        |       Pending
    2   |          1       |       20000      |         2        |       Pending
    3   |          1       |       20000      |         3        |       Pending


    4   |          2       |       20000      |         1        |       Pending
    5   |          2       |       20000      |         2        |       Pending
    6   |          2       |       20000      |         3        |       Pending
    7   |          2       |       20000      |         4        |       Pending
```

I would like to fetch only the loan amount and its respective paid months count for each loan from the entire two tables. I'm doing a query like this.

```
SELECT loan.`loan_amount`, COUNT(loan_repayment.`loan_id`) FROM loan 
LEFT OUTER JOIN loan_repayment ON 
      (loan.`id`=loan_repayment.`loan_id` AND loan_repayment.`status`='Paid' ) 
GROUP BY loan_repayment.`loan_id`
```

I'm using left outer join here so that even if the loan_repayment table is null according to the where clause, I can still get the result as 0. But the problem is, it's only returning the following data. I don't know why is it now returning the following (loan) rows after that.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             loan_amount                  |        count(loan_repayment.loan_id)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                60000                     |                     0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actully I've created a Hibernate criteria which includes many other restriction, but upon further investigating the generated sql, it narrow down to this point. Why does 2nd row data and its child data are not included in the result of the proposed sql?

Also it would be helpful if it can be replicated in hibernate criteria (Not a big deal, I can figure it out, but worried about the result of that sql).

**Update :**

If I changed the query from

```
loan_repayment.`status`='Paid'
```

to

```
loan_repayment.`status`='Pending'
```

I get the following result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             loan_amount                  |        count(loan_repayment.loan_id)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                60000                     |                     3
                80000                     |                     4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's kind of strange on why it's not producing the same result with count as 0 for the exact opposite condition.

Comment: Is that your full table?   From what I'm seeing, your results look correct for your queries.  Loan 1 (for 6000) does not have any loan repayments that are paid, so the total count of payments for that one should come up as 0.   When you change it to pending, there are 3 loan repayments, so there are 3.  Or am I misunderstanding your question(s)?  If you mean that it should return nulls, try doing a left join with just the `loan_id` and not as a count, and see what it returns.

Comment: yes it's returning as 3 and 4 if the condition is pending, then why it didnt do it the same opposite for condition paid, which the expected output would be 0 and 0 for each row. Anyhow, I'll try your suggestion. But I'm begging to understand what the problem is. I guess the cause of problem lies in my group by statement.

Comment: @nomistic, if I remove count and group by , I'm getting the expected no of rows but i can't get the count of paid rows without count function

Comment: well it did return 0;   a sum of 0 and 0 is 0.  there are no payments marked "paid."   I'm thinking what is happening that it's summing the nulls and treating them as 0.   Interesting.   One more thing, can you try grouping by `loan.loan_amount`?

Comment: anyway, since what you are looking for is the total number of payments that are marked paid, 0 is actually the correct answer, right?

Comment: @nomistic What I was looking for is every loan with its respective amount from loan table and the no of Paid payments from loan_repayment table even if it's zero (which should be returned as 0)

Comment: isn't that what you got?  You requested the number of payments.  for the number of payments that are marked "paid", that is 0 (for both loans).    For the number of payments marked "pending" that is 3 and 4 respectively. That is what you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just faced to this question while looking at previous questions with no accepted or upvoted answer.

Your query is correct except than the `group by` clause, you have grouped by a field of the table from `right side` of the `left join` (`GROUP BY loan_repayment.loan_id`), that's why you don't have the other values, you should grouped them by `loan.id`, let test it:

*Schema:*

```
create table loan( id int, loan_amount  int, loan_duration int);
insert into loan values
(1,60000,3),(2,80000,4);
create table loan_repayment (id int,loan_id int,amount int,month int,status varchar(20));
insert into loan_repayment values
(1 ,1 ,20000,1,'Pending'),(2 ,1 ,20000,2,'Pending'),(3 ,1 ,20000,3,'Pending'),
(4 ,2 ,20000,1,'Pending'),(5 ,2 ,20000,2,'Pending'),(6 ,2 ,20000,3,'Pending'),
(7 ,2 ,20000,4,'Pending');
```

now *with this query*:

```
SELECT l.loan_amount, COUNT(lr.loan_id) as Paied 
FROM loan l
LEFT OUTER JOIN loan_repayment lr ON 
      (l.id=lr.loan_id AND lr.status='paid') 
GROUP BY l.id
```

*you will get*:

```
loan_amount Paied
60000       0
80000       0
```

you can also have both `paid` and `pending` *together*:

```
SELECT l.loan_amount, SUM(CASE 
                            WHEN lr.status='paid' THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                          END) as Paied,
                       SUM(CASE 
                            WHEN lr.status='Pending' THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                          END) as Pending

FROM loan l
LEFT OUTER JOIN loan_repayment lr ON 
      (l.id=lr.loan_id) 
GROUP BY l.id
```

*Result:*

```
loan_amount Paied   Pending
60000       0       3
80000       0       4
```

You can achieve above results with Hibernate `HQL` or `Criteria` api, I don't think if it be too much difficult to map the above queries(the first query which is what you tried) to Hibernate HQL or Criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.. That works like charm.. Also thanks for the paid and pending together query..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just the wrong GROUP BY, try  `GROUP BY loan.id` as below

```
SELECT loan.`loan_amount`, COUNT(loan_repayment.`loan_id`) FROM loan 
LEFT OUTER JOIN loan_repayment ON 
      (loan.`id`=loan_repayment.`loan_id` AND loan_repayment.`status`='Paid' ) 
GROUP BY loan.id
```

Comment: The result it still the same.. If I change `loan_repayment.status='Paid'` to `loan_repayment.status='Pending'` , I'm succesfully getting two rows as result with count as 3 and 4 respectively. But If the where clause is changed to 'Paid' , it return only first row instead of two rows.

Comment: @user1354678 given the sample data you've supplied, you don't have any payments with status of paid, are you sure you want payments with that status or loan?

Comment: @dbinns66 I think the issue the user is having is due to the fact that it is not returning nulls for status "paid" and is instead summing them up and giving 0

Comment: sorry buddy.. It do works now.. But wondering why it didn't work yesterday for your suggestion. maybe i've messed up some conditions..